# c insert variable to mysql database beaglebone

Tags: mysql, c, linux, variables, insert

Working on a C project where I'm trying to insert values into a mysql database (linux debian on beaglebone black).  The code works fine when I insert constants into the database but I cannot figure out how to get variables for date/time and a double number (temperature).  Been at it for a week but cannot seem to figure it out so any insight would be appreciated.

All the assorted things I've tried either end up with a compile error, null in database or zeros.  I think I'm close... but obviously missing something, probably in the INSERT INTO line?

```
char buf[LEN];
time_t curtime;
struct tm *loc_time;

curtime = time (NULL);

loc_time = localtime (&curtime);


strftime (buf, LEN, "%Y-%m-%d" " " "%X", loc_time);
fputs (buf, stdout);


MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

if (con == NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "mysql_init() failed\n");
   exit(1);
}

if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "user", "pass", "TempDB", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) 
{
   finish_with_error(con);
}   

if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempMeas(MeasTime DATETIME, Temp DOUBLE)"))
{
    finish_with_error(con);
}

if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO TempMeas(MeasTime, Temp) VALUES('%d', '%d')", buf, j))
{    
    finish_with_error(con);
}

mysql_close(con);

exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert the actual date and time into the SQL you can do that with sql:

```
INSERT INTO TempMeas(MeasTime, Temp) VALUES(now(), 'other value');
```

you get the other values into it with:

```
#include<string.h>      # needed for sizeof()

/* all the other stuff */

char query1[999];
int num = sprintf(query1, "INSERT INTO TempMeas(MeasTime, Temp) VALUES(now(), '%d');", j);
if (num > sizeof(query1))
{
  printf("Error: Query too long.\n");
  exit (1);
}
if (mysql_query(con, query1))
{
  printf("Error: mysql_query failed.");
  exit (1);
}
```

Changed so that `query` has defined size, and checking if the actual query fits in our `char query[999]`

Comment: Tried using your 3 line code and it compiled but when I ran it it gave an error: "Segmentation fault".  I've had this error with some other things I've tried but when I use constants it inserts without problem.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ran gdb and received the following: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6b9d010 in _IO_str_overflow () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6    Then did backtrace: #0  0xb6b9d010 in _IO_str_overflow () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#1  0xb6b9c252 in _IO_default_xsputn () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#2  0xb6b7b712 in vfprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#3  0xb6b952e2 in vsprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#4  0xb6b82838 in sprintf () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
#5  0x000088e0 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbef ...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Edited post.

Comment: Awesome!  Missing a colon & a ) on the new code but once those are in it's perfect!  Many many thanks!

Comment: No problem. I found the missing ) but i can't find where a colon is missing.

Comment: Your right, it wasn't a colon (that was me) it was the variable query should be query1 for sizeof().  Thanks again Gerald, massive help for my project.